# Percentage of players who play this game each month Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This query gets the number of all active players each month from the activity table:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('month', createdat) as month,
  count(distinct playerid) as play_all
FROM
    activity
group by month
order by 1
```

And this query gets the number of players who play the game "bee" each month:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('month', createdat) as month,
  count(distinct playerid) as play_bee
FROM
    activity
where gamename = 'bee'    
group by month
order by 1
```

How can I get the percentage of players who play the game "bee" each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', createdat) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT playerid) AS play_all,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN gamename = 'bee' THEN playerid END) AS play_bee,
  100. * COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN gamename = 'bee' THEN playerid END)
       / COUNT(DISTINCT playerid) AS percent_play_bee,
FROM
    activity
group by month
order by 1
```

It uses the fact that `CASE WHEN gamename = 'bee' THEN playerid END` will return a `playerid` if `gamename = 'bee`, but will return `NONE` if it isn't. (I'm not sure if the NONE response will be included in the `COUNT(DISTINCT..)`, so it might be off by 1.)

Basically, the `CASE` is evaluated for each line is individually. Then, the values are made DISTINCT, then they are counted.